# ImpressPages 4: Not all pages have the same width

Tags: themes, width, impresspages

There is a strange behaviour in one of my installations with ImpressPages: Not all pages have the same width.

I'm using the default theme "Air".

The installation is at

http://www.impresspages.ch

It is the page "Link" that has not the same width as the other pages.

Any idea what causes this?

Comment: I have found a solution for this at

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311504/long-pages-in-firefox-offset-when-scrollbar-appears

Answer (score 0):

Your website looks normal. Maybe you see that center content goes slightly to the left on that page? If that's the case, it means that on your screen that page gets a visible scrollbar. And the browser you use hides/shows the scrollbar only when it's needed. For that reason the area for the page shrinks and automated centering ends up on a different position.

Comment: Thank you, that's it! Silly me, I never was aware of this.

Comment: Then select the answer as the best one. Others will be able to see.

Comment: This is not yet possible. Because I have have not enough reputation.